# Self signed certificate in certificate chain - NuGetToolInstaller

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuget-package

I have configured an Azure DevOps pipeline. When I try to run NuGetToolInstaller, I received `ERR:self signed certificate in certificate chain`. What is the solution to this error?

[image: Azure Devops Dashboard Error Output]

Comment: Do you have a company proxy that decrypts https traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Azure DevOps service, and your organization is secured with a firewall or proxy server, you need to add certain IP addresses and domain URLs to the **Allow list** by following this doc: [Allowed address lists and network connections](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fsecurity%2Fallow-list-ip-url%3Fview%3Dazure-devops&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7C7333b64e57b74a22066808d8c33e4fa2%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637474019678961394%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=n7pM3V9gY3mak2EMCgUzgZG6caPbdINU%2F2yKGkwvydg%3D&reserved=0). And if you use self-hosted agents, please follow this doc: [Run a self-hosted agent behind a web proxy](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fpipelines%2Fagents%2Fproxy%3Fview%3Dazure-devops%26tabs%3Dwindows&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7C7333b64e57b74a22066808d8c33e4fa2%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637474019678961394%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=rDCyQO11E0VKOaAQts2yR8VgNNxv8Io4wBcoY%2B6VrK0%3D&reserved=0) to configure your agent.

If you use on-premise Azure DevOps Server, please refer to this doc: [Run the agent with a self-signed certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/certificate?view=azure-devops-2022) to check this issue.

In addition, if you recently changed your account, you could refer to this [thread](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F58522318%2Fgit-error-in-azure-devops-ssl-certificate-problem-self-signed-certificate-in&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7C7333b64e57b74a22066808d8c33e4fa2%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637474019678981381%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=zZ%2BVX6oStsnHjiOGa1kSlyhyGCac%2F%2F4REu0GsGy%2BBUI%3D&reserved=0) to check if its solution works for your issue.

BTW, you could [review debug logs to diagnose pipeline issues](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fpipelines%2Ftroubleshooting%2Freview-logs%3Fview%3Dazure-devops&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7C7333b64e57b74a22066808d8c33e4fa2%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637474019678981381%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=O5kFLa199U9AxGsntBIEnNGVOjTGDbGbw5cRCUGpaxQ%3D&reserved=0).

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was caused by the fact that I was using a proxy which in turns uses custom root SSL certificates.
I fixed this in Windows Server by exporting the root certificates needed in a PEM file, which should look something like:

```
GlobalSign Root CA
==================
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Entrust.net Premium 2048 Secure Server CA
=========================================
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEKjCCAxKgAwIBAgIEOGPe+DANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBtDEUMBIGA1UEChMLRW50cnVzdC5u
ZXQxQDA+BgNVBAsUN3d3dy5lbnRydXN0Lm5ldC9DUFNfMjA0OCBpbmNvcnAuIGJ5IHJlZi4gKGxp
bWl0cyBsaWFiLikxJTAjBgNVBAsTHChjKSAxOTk5IEVudHJ1c3QubmV0IExpbWl0ZWQxMzAxBgNV
BAMTKkVudHJ1c3QubmV0IENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5ICgyMDQ4KTAeFw05OTEyMjQx
NzUwNTFaFw0yOTA3MjQxNDE1MTJaMIG0MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtFbnRydXN0Lm5ldDFAMD4GA1UECxQ3
d3d3LmVudHJ1c3QubmV0L0NQU18yMDQ4IGluY29ycC4gYnkgcmVmLiAobGltaXRzIGxpYWIuKTEl
MCMGA1UECxMcKGMpIDE5OTkgRW50cnVzdC5uZXQgTGltaXRlZDEzMDEGA1UEAxMqRW50cnVzdC5u
ZXQgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBBdXRob3JpdHkgKDIwNDgpMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8A
MIIBCgKCAQEArU1LqRKGsuqjIAcVFmQqK0vRvwtKTY7tgHalZ7d4QMBzQshowNtTK91euHaYNZOL
Gp18EzoOH1u3Hs/lJBQesYGpjX24zGtLA/ECDNyrpUAkAH90lKGdCCmziAv1h3edVc3kw37XamSr
hRSGlVuXMlBvPci6Zgzj/L24ScF2iUkZ/cCovYmjZy/Gn7xxGWC4LeksyZB2ZnuU4q941mVTXTzW
nLLPKQP5L6RQstRIzgUyVYr9smRMDuSYB3Xbf9+5CFVghTAp+XtIpGmG4zU/HoZdenoVve8AjhUi
VBcAkCaTvA5JaJG/+EfTnZVCwQ5N328mz8MYIWJmQ3DW1cAH4QIDAQABo0IwQDAOBgNVHQ8BAf8E
BAMCAQYwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUVeSB0RGAvtiJuQijMfmhJAkWuXAwDQYJ
KoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBADubj1abMOdTmXx6eadNl9cZlZD7Bh/KM3xGY4+WZiT6QBshJ8rmcnPy
T/4xmf3IDExoU8aAghOY+rat2l098c5u9hURlIIM7j+VrxGrD9cv3h8Dj1csHsm7mhpElesYT6Yf
zX1XEC+bBAlahLVu2B064dae0Wx5XnkcFMXj0EyTO2U87d89vqbllRrDtRnDvV5bu/8j72gZyxKT
J1wDLW8w0B62GqzeWvfRqqgnpv55gcR5mTNXuhKwqeBCbJPKVt7+bYQLCIt+jerXmCHG8+c8eS9e
nNFMFY3h7CI3zJpDC5fcgJCNs2ebb0gIFVbPv/ErfF6adulZkMV8gzURZVE=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Save this to a file, example c:\ca.pem
Then set the environment variable:

```
set NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=C:\ca.pem
```

Restart the ADO agent so that it picks up the new environment variable and then it should just work.

This is because the ADO tasks, and in particular the NuGetToolInstaller@1 task uses a versions of Node that does not picks up the certificates installed in the Windows certificate store. In this way we make node aware of the custom certificates.

Credit https://github.com/jasongin/nvs/issues/87